# How to access a Storyboard's segue through code?

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

There are couple for segues in the storyboard, all with identifier. Is it possible to access them through code and change its anchor?

Something like this:

```
mySegue1.anchor = someOtherView
```

Comment: What is the `anchor` of a segue you are referring to?

Comment: @Iman My problem is different, in that question he does not set anchor programmatically, just change the frame size.

Comment: Thanks for clarification I wil give dup flag back

Comment: @Iman I'll appreciate it if you remove the flag.

Comment: @Maysam I am 100 percent sure that there is a way to change an anchor of a segue programmatically since xcode uses that to draw storyboard from sks or xib or change the content of sks or xib files. but I didnt try to find it.

Comment: Why did you used a Segue? I think it is very clear and straightforward, just dont use storyboard for Gesture Recognizer and pop over menu!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Comment: I asked for accessing segue not performing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may chnage anchor's view controller with the following codes, as I wrote in above  comments, I believe you can create a Segue programmatically  and the following code will create a new Segue for you not just change an old already drawn Segue's anchor programmatically.

> Most of the good programmers think that you can not create a Segue by code, thats why changing a Segue anchor is not believed to be a performable job. But it is

It is an 'Objective C' version but you may easily convert it to 'Swift' if you like.

```
UIViewController *toViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherViewControllerId"]; 

MySegue *segue = [[MySegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"" source:self destination:toViewController]; 

[self prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender]; 

[segue perform];
```

However if you need to create a popover menu using a gesture recognizer, then just create a gesture recognizer and activate your pop over in gesture's action func ( handleTap() )
take a look at the following link, you may create your popover in storyboard and then write the rest of the code or completely do it by code, both are fully covered here.

http://gracefullycoded.com/display-a-popover-in-swift/

as I understood which I hope I get it right, you are about to create a pop over on your view controller which has a tab gesture defined on it. and you succeed to do the job but the pop over menu is mislocated. if this is the case You dont need to use a segue or a storyboard, all parts can be done by code easily.

Comment: To make it clear: I have dynamically created objects and a UITapGestureRecognizer is attached to them. Their place on screen is random, and when user double taps on them a popover shows up. it's why  I need to change anchor programatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is making an invisible anchor frame (ie a label ) and using that as anchor for the segue. I had som buttons and use this approach and it works fine. If you replace my buttons with you dynamically created objects.

```
@IBAction func rearHubActionUIButton(sender: UIButton) {
        invisibleAncherLabel.frame = sender.frame
        performSegueWithIdentifier("PopSelection", sender: sender)
    }
```

The popover will then appear with your object as anchor.